# How to selectively update fields (profile details) only filled by the user in the form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend, serverside-javascript

I need to update users profile details, but my form only works when all input fields are filled, how do I only update those profile details, which are filled in the form.

My form has 4 fields updatable: Name, Email, Age, Password, and I am accepting them in this form :

```
<h1>Update profile details</h1>
    <form action="" id="update-profile-form">
        <input type="text" id="update-name" placeholder="New Name"> 


        <input type="text" id="update-email" placeholder="New Email"> 


        <input type="text" id="update-age" placeholder="New Age"> 


        <input type="text" id="update-password" placeholder="New Password"> 


        <button id="update-button">Update Filled</button>
        <p id="update-details"></p>
    </form>
```

My server-side JS code is :

```
const updateForm = document.querySelector( "#update-profile-form" );
updateForm.addEventListener( "submit", ( e ) => {
    const name = document.querySelector( "#update-name" ).value;
    const email = document.querySelector( "#update-email" ).value;
    const age = document.querySelector( "#update-age" ).value;
    const password = document.querySelector( "#update-password" ).value;

    console.log( 'Profile update request' );
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch( "http://localhost:3000/users/me", {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ` + `${ inMemoryToken }`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( {
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "age": age,
            "password": password
        } )
    } ).then( res => res.json() )
        .then( res => {
            console.log( res );
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector( "#update-details" ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify( res );
           
        }
        );
} );
```

My backend NodeJS code is :

```
router.patch( "/users/me", auth, async ( req, res ) => {
    const updates = Object.keys( req.body );
    const allowedUpdates = [ "name", "email", "password", "age" ];
    const isValidOperation = updates.every( ( update ) =>
        allowedUpdates.includes( update )
    );

    if ( !isValidOperation ) {
        return res.status( 400 ).send( { error: "Invalid updates" } );
    }

    try {
        updates.forEach( ( update ) => ( req.user[ update ] = req.body[ update ] ) );
        await req.user.save();

        res.status( 201 ).send( req.user );
    } catch ( e ) {
        res.status( 404 ).send( {
            e,
        } );
    }
} );
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Please feel free to ask any questions about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `console.log(updates)` just before the line `updates.forEach( ( update ) => ( req.user[ update ] = req.body[ update ] ) );` in your backend code.

After checking what the values come in as on a partial form, you should be able to change it to something like:

```
updates.forEach(update => {
    if (req.body[update] != "") {
        req.user[update] = req.body[update] 
    }
});
```

So that it only applies the update if the request is not an empty string (depends what the default "empty" value is on your form).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Luke, it perfectly worked. Also, can you please give this one a look as well, I will be grateful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587902/how-to-upload-image-using-multer-through-browser